# Hudson integration for Maven projects

Tags: maven-2, continuous-integration, hudson, hudson-plugins

I have few maven projects.They have testNG test cases too.Tests run fine.Now I want to integrate the projects with Hudson for getting basic features such as subversion updates, test reports, sending email etc.Projects are built in java 1.5.What is the hudson compatible version for Java 1.5 and also gives the possibility to add maven 2 module, configure subversion.The version I downloaded had some java version issues.Then I replaces the jar which was causing issue but still could not configure the project for svn stuff.Please help me, is there a guide of step by step walk through...Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you looket at the hudson book available online at http://www.eclipse.org/hudson/the-hudson-book/book-hudson.chunked/ ?

Comment: Which kind of issues with Java? The platform for Hudson is different of the java version which you use for your builds.

Comment: it was a problem with jmdns jar. I replaced it with an old version, then it was okay. I dont remember the error exactly but it was something like, bad version...

Answer (score 0):

`What is the hudson compatible version for Java 1.5 ?`

As you have already figured out, [the latest Hudson versions require Java 6](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Installing+Hudson).  **However, the Java JRE that Hudson runs on IS NOT the Java JRE/JDK that your project will use to compile, test, and package itself in Maven.**

The version of Java Hudson uses to compile your project is an option you select in the Hudson UI (Manage Hudson).  In fact, Hudson can compile and test your Maven project against multiple versions of Java if you wish.

This is a powerful capability of Hudson that is not immediately obvious.  See the following screenshot for details:

[image]

So the bottom line is this:  *Use the latest version of Hudson (or Jenkins) and set the JDK installation to v1.5.*